# How to remove hashset items to another hashset

Tags: c#

I have two hashsets (`HashSet<T> SetA` and `HashSet<T> SetB`) that I need to move x amount of items from one to the next for processing.  Basically I am creating a queue system and I don't want to go through each one.

Take X items from `SetA` and put on `SetB`
Process `SetB`
Loop until `SetA` is empty.

Things that did not work:

```
BatchRecords.ToList().AddRange(AllOftheRecords.ToList().Take(maxRecords));

BatchRecords.ToList().AddRange(AllOftheRecords.Take(maxRecords));
```

Neither were the items removed nor where they added to the batchrecords list.

I am hoping to avoid a foreach loop since it is essential get the top 100 records and insert them in to another list.

Comment: you should show us what you have done

Comment: Remove `ToList()` You create a new list and don't assign it to a variable (BTW HashSet doesn't have a method `AddRange`. Either give an Enumerable at constructor or add one by one)...

Comment: Is there a need for `HashSet` as opposed to working with a `Queue` built from a list filtered with `Distinct()`? The semantics of inserting and removing from a `HashSet` will likely make implementing your own queue rather slow and prone to errors.

Comment: `var temp = AllOftheRecords.Take(maxRecords).ToList(); AllOftheRecords.ExceptWith(temp); BatchRecords.UnionWith(temp);`

Comment: You really need to show us a [mcve]. You start out with variables called `SetA` and `SetB`, but then show us code with variables `BatchRecords` and `AllOftheRecords`. It's confusing. We should be able to copy, paste, and run your code to see what is happening. Then we can very easily fix your code. Right now you're making us do a lot of work to help you and that limits how many good answers you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will not work as you intend because `BatchRecords.ToList()` creates a new object, a `List`, that then gets augmented with the result of `AllOftheRecords.ToList().Take(maxRecords)`. The `Take` method does not remove anything from the origin, it just generates a projection (IEnumerable) with the number of items you requested (`maxRecords`).

Both original objects, `BatchRecords` and `AllOftheRecords` remain unchanged after those operations.

Unfortunately `HashSet` does not have a `AddRange` like `List` does.

You can either change your HashSet to a list or use a loop to remove objects from it.